# Why are pages in my Rails app being requested with a TXT mime type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, mime-types, mime

I'm getting quite a lot of traffic requesting a txt version of my site homepage. It appears that the mime type of the request header has been set to text/*. They are not requesting the homepage with a .txt suffix, they appear to be manipulating the http request directly.

My questions are:

1. Is this a hack attempt?
2. If yes, what information could a hacker get at by manipulating a mime type like this?

Comment: This not off topic according to the FAQ. It's a specific, reasonably scoped, programming problem. I disagree.

Comment: This question should be re-opened as it's not off topic according to the FAQ. It's a specific, programming related issue.